# How to upload photo into main album at my community via vk_api

Tags: python-3.x, api, upload, vk

If I use login and password to auth I get "vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [203] Access to group denied"

If I use access token I get "vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [27] Group authorization failed: method is unavailable with group auth."

First way:

```
def upload_pic(filename, album_id, group_id):
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login=LOGIN, password=PASSWORD)
    try:
        vk_session.auth(token_only=True)
    except vk_api.AuthError as error_msg:
        print(error_msg)
        return
    upload = vk_api.VkUpload(vk_session)

    upload.photo(filename, album_id, group_id=group_id)
```

Second way:

```
def upload_pic(filename, album_id, group_id):
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=TOKEN)
    upload = vk_api.VkUpload(vk_session)
    upload.photo(filename, album_id, group_id=group_id)
```

I tried to add auth block from first way to second one but it nothing changed
[rights for token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Y1wZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is the reason but i remembered that vk_api uses keyword args

In general here's the working code

```
def upload_pic(filename, album_id, group_id):
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login=LOGIN, password=PASSWORD)
    try:
        vk_session.auth(token_only=True)
    except vk_api.AuthError as error_msg:
        print(error_msg)
        return
    upload = vk_api.VkUpload(vk_session)
    upload.photo(filename, album_id=album_id, group_id=group_id)
```